# How to achieve the results below in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

*Task: To look at each employee id and sort by REQUEST_DATE. Then create a FROM and TO QUEUE_TYPE_ID. So I would like to see which QUEUE did this employee move from - to. The latest **QUEUE_TYPE_ID_TO** should be empty since the employee is stuck in the FROM QUEUE.*

Start with this:
Table ABC

| EMPLOYE_ID | QUEUE_TYPE_ID_FROM | QUEUE_TYPE_ID_TO | REQUEST_DATE | PARTION_BY_NUM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | R366 | R366 | 3/5/2021 | 1 |
| 1 | R286 | R366 | 6/5/2020 | 2 |
| 1 | R286 | R366 | 5/6/2018 | 1 |
| 1 | R156 | R366 | 2/5/2018 | 1 |

End with this:
Table XYZ

| EMPLOYE_ID | QUEUE_TYPE_ID_FROM | QUEUE_TYPE_ID_TO | REQUEST_DATE_FROM | REQUEST_DATE_TO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | R366 | NULL | /5/2021 | NULL |
| 1 | R286 | R366 | 6/5/2020 | 3/5/2021 |
| 1 | R156 | R286 | 2/5/2018 | 6/5/2020 |

Comment: it is calles ppivot and if you want it dynamic yiu need dynamic sql but even then how the row are connected must be in a cloumn else you can't build aa relationship

Comment: I was thinking to make a case statement that says if the queue_type_id_from to queue_type_id_to matches then change the queue_type_id_to to the latest queue_type_id_from with the latest date. That is why I have the partition_by_num in the first table.

Comment: CASE WHEN QUEUE_TYPE_ID_FROM = QUEUE_TYPE_ID_FROM_TO THEN NULL ELSE (SELECT QUEUE_TYPE_ID_FROM FROM ABC WHERE PARTION_BY_NUM=2) END QUEUE_TYPE_ID_TO -- Does that work?

Comment: you should ret5hnk your conceptm look for recursive CTE or if you have an older version of cte you need to look for hirachys in mysql or rountrip there are some allproches, but in short to now the gebigging it must be maekd and there must breadcrums that follow till the end. if you have multiple R286 as start you need to identify the endpoint for **every ** start point