# I would like to transform the SQL table into a FROM and TO columns

Tags: sql

Here we have the first table as 2 columns and ID and Date. Now I would like to take the Earliest ID and bring the ID above it right next to it. So in other words, a CASE statement that says "If the REQUET_DATE for the earliest ID is smaller then then the REQUEST_DATE for the second ID then bring it next to it"

| QUEUE_TYPE_ID | REQUEST_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| R366 | 3/5/2021 |
| R286 | 6/5/2020 |
| R156 | 2/5/2018 |

| QUEUE_TYPE_ID_FROM | QUEUE_TYPE_ID_TO | REQUEST_DATE_FROM | REQUEST_DATE_TO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R366 | NULL | 3/5/2021 | NULL |
| R286 | R366 | 6/5/2020 | 3/5/2021 |
| R156 | R286 | 2/5/2018 | 6/5/2020 |

Comment: Search for `LAG` and `LEAD` in the documentation for whatever database engine you're using. They're windowing functions.

Comment: Also, don't keep asking the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69887682/how-to-achieve-the-results-below-in-sql) over and over. See [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for tips.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a repeat of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69887682/how-to-achieve-the-results-below-in-sql

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.